# How to Update Azure User Password? Get Error Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

How to Update Azure User Password?
My Code is like below

```
PasswordProfile PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
{
    Password = "newp@134",
    ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = false
};
user.PasswordProfile = PasswordProfile;
//user.SignInNames = "";

await user.UpdateAsync();
```

I give permission in application in azure portal also.

`Application    User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`

`Delegated (personal Microsoft account) User.ReadWrite`

Still get error .`enter code here`
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

I want to update any User password not just Sign in User.

Comment: Hey if my answer helpful you could accept it by right click beside the gray button of question to help the community.

Answer (score 0):

> You are doing little wrong while updating the `passwordProfile property`, one additional permission is required that is: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All.`

***`Solution:`***

You should have `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`  `Delegated Permission` on azure portal(For Signin user and `Application permission for (non signin user)`).

[image]

***Note:***

[image]

Please refer to [Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for details.

Comment: I added Directory.AccessAsUser.All Delegated Permission already..But still not working

Comment: I want to update any User password not just Sign in User.

Comment: No, only a sign in user can changed his password like this. please refer to given document.